# A discussion about moderator qualifications

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

In your personal opinion, what qualifications should a person have to become a moderator of an Islamic community page ?

Comment: We are not an Islamic community page. We are a Q&A site about the *topic* of Islam.

Comment: No, you are. Majority of questions are from Muslim pepole asking questions **in** Islam specifics and answers are given about topics **in** Islam makes this form an Islamic community. If the majority of questions are from non-muslims **about** Islam,  then it s about Islam. Activity defines identity.

Comment: If you open a shop that has a banner "Library" and all is done inside is serving food dishes, then it is a restaurant not a library.

Comment: Mayhap, but if you open a shop that has a banner "Library", it doesn't become a restaurant just because everyone insists on bringing their food in to eat instead of reading books. It just means a lot of people are in the wrong place.

Comment: see also: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/189/22

Comment: No , it does mean. Notice that I wrote "served" not "brought" , which implies that the owner of the shop is the one who is serving the dishes, and the moderators here are answering questions in Islam.

Comment: If the owner of the shop do not agree on converting his shop to a restaurant, then he will prevent those coming with the food.

Comment: Instead of the keen interest in making irrelevant corrections in every person's posts , moderate the questions that you consider against the target of the community if you do not agree, if any .

Comment: To me this question seems totally off-topic here. But it might be asked on the main site.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange sites are secular sites for information sharing. This is not an Islamic site, it is a secular site for sharing knowledge about Islam. There are already enough of Islamic sites on the internet, if you are interested in Islamic sites in place of a secular site for sharing information about Islam then you are probably in the wrong place.

Comment: I seek nothing. I never asked here,  I only answer. And indeed you are answering the wrong question : your  answer is about the comments between me and goldPseduo, not the question. The question is about the assumed moderator's qualifications. Please re-read the question.

Comment: I am answering the question by pointing out that an assumption inside the question is incorrect. This is not an "Islamic community page", this is a secular Q&A website inside the Stack Exchange network whose topic is Islam, it is not an Islamic website. The qualifications for being a moderator are similar to qualifications on other SE website, see [a theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), [election post on Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/1), and [election post on Judaism](http://Judaism.stackexchange.com/election/1).

Answer (score 0):

Even if I think this question is off-topic here I'm answering it.

An Islamic community page would have a webmaster who is the only person who posts on the site, as it would only be a website. A moderator is needed once a page is more or less an internet forum. And even then a moderator would be appointed according the usual ways:

- either because he is very active,
- he seems to have some knowledge,
- he was well accepted by the community,
- and the most common reason would be: That he knows or is a friend the webmaster or is a relative!

On the other hand in any internet forum there are rules to follow or unwritten law it's the job of mods to take care of them being applied.

**An advise** (even if I have given it to you several times I'm repeating myself):

You are now a few months visiting this site, but until now you still -as it seems- never took the [tour](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/tour) or visited our [help center](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how this site works. This might be a major reason for your conflicts with moderators and the community itself.

Comment: (and @goldPsequdo), about this answer, it seems that I have done a long edition (2299 characters) about it, but I have not done it at all. I wanna know if I've been hacked or and error of the site (which has done by my user name)?